# Filtering undefined promises with BlueBird + React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, rss, promise, bluebird

I am attempting to fetch multiple rss feeds, get each of their promises, and use bluebird to merge the arrays of each returned promises to get an array of relevant content for the user.

However, on occasion some rss feeds are down or don't have images, and those promises returned an undefined where an array should be as shown below:

[image]

So I am looking for a way to filter out these bad promises and keep the good ones. I am very new to bluebird and promises in general, and would appreciate any help. Here's my code now (that doesn't filter out any promises at all, but does merge their arrays):

```
//combining promises
    var that = this; 
    return Promise.all(rss_feeds)
      .then((res) => {
          for (var q = 0; q < res.length; q++)
          {
            for (var a =0; a < res[q].length; a++)
            {
              final_array.push(res[q][a]);
            }
          }
          //console.log('The following array of objects was constructed and is now being shuffled');
          //console.log(final_array.length);
          that.shuffle(final_array);
          //console.log(final_array);
          return final_array;
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a value is wrapped in a `Promise`, the only way of inspecting it is to use the `.then` method. As a matter of fact, the reason why promises are so powerful is that `.then` allows manipulating the wrapped value without caring of its actual existence. In other words, promises represent the computational context of an eventual value.

As a consequence, you first need to move from an array of promises to a promise of an array with `Promise#all` and then reason on the eventual array of values (some of which might be `undefined`). After that, you can filter and return a new promise comprising only the desired values.

This leads to:

```
// dummy values to simulate the use case
var arrayOfPromises = [Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(undefined), Promise.resolve(2)]

var result = Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(ps => ps.filter(p => p));
result.then(console.log.bind(console));  // output: [1, 2]
```

Note that Bluebird provides an additional `Promise#filter` method as a shorthand. However, the above code has the advantage of working with bluebird and native ES6 promises alike.